# Adding Visibility Analysis algorithms to standalone QGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I'm writing a script to compute the intervisibility between two sets of points using the **Intervisibility** algorithm from the **Visibility Analysis** plugin which (to my knowledge) is installed by default in QGIS and available in the processing toolbox.

It needs to be standalone because I intend to pipeline and parallelize the process and don't want the interface/overhead of the application. Using the in-application python console to list the available algorithms,

```
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    print(f"{alg.id()} --> {alg.displayName()}")
```

I get the following options at the end of the list.

```
...
qgis:vectorlayerscatterplot --> Vector layer scatterplot
qgis:voronoipolygons --> Voronoi polygons
visibility:Intervisibility --> Intervisibility network
visibility:Viewshed --> Viewshed
visibility:create_viewpoints --> Create viewpoints
```

I understand that to use these algorithms in the standalone script I need to add the algorithms provider. I do so using the following code.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('/home/USER/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/'))

from qgis.core import QgsApplication

from ViewshedAnalysis.visibility_provider import VisibilityProvider
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(VisibilityProvider())
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
```

However, the same code to list the algorithms now ends with,

```
...
qgis:vectorlayerscatterplot --> Vector layer scatterplot
qgis:voronoipolygons --> Voronoi polygons
: --> 
: --> 
: -->
```

And, calls to `visibility:Intervisibility` fail with `Algorithm not found` error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the part

```py
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(VisibilityProvider())
```

with the following

```
visibilityProvider = VisibilityProvider()
visibilityProvider.setActive(True)
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(visibilityProvider)
```

FYI, deduced from https://github.com/zoran-cuckovic/QGIS-visibility-analysis/blob/master/visibility_provider.py#L82